# How can I Implement spin in billiard game?

Tags: unity, c#, billiards

I'm not sure that you played billiard or snooker before.if you played you should know about spin.
but anyway if you don't know about it you can see it in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYqnHERu8SA)

I want to Implement spin like [this game](http://www.flyordie.com/snooker/)

[image: _39103267_snooker_spin_2_298]

for example difference between Top spin and Back spin is:

**[Top spin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topspin)**

[image: Record_2019_03_12_00_35_03_630]

**[Back spin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspin)**

[image: Record_2019_03_12_00_35_39_151]

---

**Spin behaviour**

if you aim behind the ball you can shoot the ball in all direction

[image: A]

---

if you aim closest to right you can just aim the right

[image: B]

if you aim closest to left you can just aim the left

[image: C]

---

I found a same Issue that used Torque in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27705457/spin-physics-issue-in-unity3d) but I don't know why didn't work!

**Top Spin**

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddTorque(Vector3.back * cueStrength );
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForceAtPosition(cueStick.forward * cueStrength,transform.position,ForceMode.Acceleration);
```

[image: Record_2019_03_12_00_47_45_936]

**Back Spin**

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddTorque(Vector3.forward * cueStrength );
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForceAtPosition(cueStick.forward * cueStrength,transform.position,ForceMode.Acceleration);
```

[image: Record_2019_03_12_00_45_23_544]

I noticed that [flyordie's snooker](http://www.flyordie.com/snooker/) didn't use AddTorque.so I don't need answer that Implemented with AddTorque.

---

## Update

**What I tried**

I add joystick to select spin angle

[image]

then I apply spin force ( It seems my spin works but sometimes didn't work that I attached video in end of my question).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

this is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MainBall : MonoBehaviour {

    private Vector3 FirstPos; // store first position as reset position
    public Transform SpinRoator; // spin rotator cylinder that show spin angle
    private Rigidbody rigidbody;
    public bool SpinUsed; // spin should use once
    private float v2;

    private void Start() {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        FirstPos = transform.position;
    }


    //After goal reset ball position
    public void ResetPos(){
        rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
        transform.position = FirstPos;

    }


    void SpinForce(){
        SpinUsed = true;
        float F = ComebackForce(); // calculate comeback force
        StopBall(); // stop ball
        rigidbody.AddForce(SpinRoator.forward*F);// apply spin force
    }


    // calculating return force after hitting f = m.a
    float ComebackForce(){
        var m = rigidbody.mass;
    var v1 = rigidbody.velocity.magnitude;

    var a = (v1 - v2) / Time.deltaTime;
        var F = m * a;
        v2 = rigidbody.velocity.magnitude;
        return F;
    }

    //stop ball
    public void StopBall(){
      rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    }


private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other) {
    if(other.collider.tag == "Ball" || other.collider.tag == "ColorfulBall"){
    if(!SpinUsed){
    SpinForce();
    }
    }
}
}
```

## but What is Problem?!

It seems works correctly but My Problem is sometimes Spin don't work correctly you can see [this video](https://youtu.be/DEgX-5sqMkU) that demonstrate this problem.my ball goes wrong direction of spin!!!

**1.Ball goes Wrong sometimes**

[image]

as you can see in above gif ball goes wrong direction!!! ball should go along yellow cylinder but I don't know what is problem of my code!!!

**1.Ball goes slow sometimes**

[image]

another problem is comeback force is slow sometimes!!!
I calculate comeback force `F = m.a` but why is it slow?!

Comment: The Unity physics engine is good enough for most games, but if you want to develop a game where it is extremely important to get the physics exactly right, like a billard simulation for example, you might have to write your own physics.

Comment: @Philipp I don't know how can I Implement custom physic.but I think it's possible to recreate Spins with default physic.but anyway I hope someone help me to Implement custom physic for billiard

Comment: This question is too broad. We could help if you had a system already working and needed assistance with specific issues. Rocket League, for example, used Bullet physics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_(software)

Comment: @Almo why should I use Bullet physic? Is there a problem in unity built-in physic problem?

Comment: A quick google searched turned this up. https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2015/09/02/rocket-league-making-of/

Comment: Why is the preview using different physics as the shoot itself?

Comment: If I recall my physics classes, much of the spin actually comes from friction between the cue and the ball, not just the impact.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if my idea will be good enough for you, but you can try it - maybe while aiming, you can store the info on what did the player do (a simple way would be to store a vector... "Player aimed at center horizontally and +5% vertically) and then, when you hit a ball, stop it completely for a frame and add a force that would be calculated with the spin included?

Comment: Can you explain how this is different from the `AddForceAtPosition(...)` solution that OP already attempted?

Comment: I did this before but I have problem I will update my answer and explain this problem https://youtu.be/DEgX-5sqMkU

Comment: @DMGregory my first solution was realistic way that used Torque but It didn't work.apply force after collision solution is fake way to apply spin force.

Comment: @DMGregory I updated my question and add this fake way but I don't know why I have problem sometimes.I tested it several times but I don't know why ball goes wrong.

Comment: @DMGregory I think problem is where I used SpinRoator.forward but apply force along SpinRoator.forward is correct!!!

Comment: @DMGregory another solution is two-directional friction but I don't know how can I use it https://twitter.com/AnthonyYakovlev/status/1115529368632270848

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamali, I know this is an old post, but if this was an open-source project, could you post the GitHub link? I've been working on something similar but was stuck on how to implement this spin effect as well.